# Python 3.6 subprocess module returncode with tee command

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, tee

I am using Python 3.6.9 to call the following bash script:

**`run_cmds.sh`**:

```sh
ls dir_doesnt_exist | tee log
```

Here is the Python code:

```py
import subprocess 
from subprocess import PIPE

cmd = subprocess.run(['bash','run_cmds.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

print(cmd.stderr.decode())
print("The returned code is:", cmd.returncode)
```

Running the Python code, I get the following:

```
ls: cannot access 'dir_doesnt_exist': No such file or directory

The returned code is: 0
```

As you can see, subprocess captures the standard error output but `returncode` is `0`.

What is wrong with my Python script?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return code IS 0. The return code is the return code of the last command, even when using `tee` (unless the pipefail variable is set). You can see it for yourself on the command line:

```
$ ls dir_doesnt_exist | tee log
ls: dir_doesnt_exist: No such file or directory

$ echo $?
0
```

However, if you remove the pipe `|`, you will get a non-zero exit code

```
$ ls dir_doesnt_exist
ls: dir_doesnt_exist: No such file or directory

$ echo $?
1
```

So, when using `tee`, you have to check the $PIPETSTATUS variable instead of the regular exit code

```
$ ls dir_doesnt_exist | tee log
ls: dir_doesnt_exist: No such file or directory

$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
1
```

Try making your python code like this

```
import subprocess 
from subprocess import PIPE

cmd = subprocess.run(['bash','run_cmds.sh; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

print(cmd.stderr.decode())
print("The returned code is:", cmd.returncode)
```